# Ошибка C2440 в C++ при создании объекта

Tags: c++

Создал класс хэш-таблицы. Вот код:

```
class hashtable {
private:
    sortedlist *arr;
    int arrSize;
public:
    hashtable (int s) {
        arrSize = s;
        arr = new sortedlist[arrSize];
    }

    void insert (link* l) {
        int hashInd = hashFunc(l->getKey());
        arr[hashInd].insert(l);
    }

    int hashFunc (int n) { return n % arrSize; }   
};
```

Выдается ошибка *C2440* при создании объекта:

```
hashtable ht = new hashtable(5);
```

В чем я не прав? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виду существования C++11, имеет смысл здесь использовать `auto`

```
auto ht=new hashtable(5);
```

В данном конкретном случае, `auto` вполне уместно, так как дает возможность избежать очевидного дублирования.

Answer (score 2):

`new hashtable` возвращает указатель, напишите `hashtable* ht`.